# scroll automatically to target with jQuery in iOS running too far

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have an anchor that when click I have the following jQuery firing:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function (event, ui) {
    var page = $(event.target);
    page.find('a.course_name').on('vclick', function() {
        page.stop().animate({ scrollTop : $(this).offset().top }, 400);
    }        
}
```

What I am finding on the iPhone 5 running iOS 6 is that the animation of the scroll doesn't stop at the top of the anchor as I would like. It sometimes stops short, or runs past dependant on what I have scrolled to in the page previously.

I am also using jQuery Mobile, but essentially the `page` variable is the scrollable area.

Comment: Are you adding the code inside `$(document).ready(function(){` ? If not, that might be the cause, as some images, videos or text could still being loading while you try to scroll and therefore the position changes once they load.

Comment: @Alvaro It is inside a `$(document).on('pageinit')` as I am using jQuery Mobile. I have updated the question accordingly. I have a background image running in a carousel, but both carousel slides are the same height - so this wouldn't change the container height.

Comment: I'm not sure about how you look for the target or what the `page` var contains but... it seems you are not scrolling to its position as you are not using it. Wouldn't it have to be something like ` scrollTop : page.offset().top ` ?

Comment: @Alvaro Apologies, I forgot a line in the sample code. The animation is triggered on click of a link with a specific class.

Comment: Don't you have a jsfiddle where we can see what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried to use `position` instead of `offset`? I don't know your HTML or CSS markup, and depending on it, it can reurn different results. Try `$(this).position().top`

Comment: @Alvaro Ah, `position` provides _much_ better results than `offset` and consistently too. Many thanks for this, happy to accept this as an answer if you want to submit.

Comment: Answer added. Your welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your HTML markup or your CSS styles, but depending on it, `position` can return a different result than `offset`.

Try it with `position()` instead:

```
page.stop().animate({ scrollTop : $(this).position().top }, 400);
```